# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Single Sign On Error - SAML SSO Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, single-sign-on, saml

We are trying to configure Single Sign On with our Salesforce Marketing Cloud Instance. SFMC is our SP while Microsoft Azure is our IdP.

We have been following this link to setup the Single Sign On
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_enable_saml_task.htm&type=5

After following the instructions, we were able to complete the configuration. However, we have been getting this error:

SAML SSO Error
An error occurred during your SAML SSO Login

None of the configured SessionInitiators handled the request.

Does anybody know what we need to work on to sort this out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I had this error also.  I forgot that Salesforce federationID is case sensitive, so if your source identity is in hump case First.Last@company.com make sure it matches exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I was just getting this same error.

Turns out that my federation ID was off by one letter.

If I were you, I would double check that.